# How to transform the model with a select component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-options

I want to sent to backend an attribute of the model value. To do that, I have a directive that draws a select input, with all the selectable values

**Context**: We have a Grails domain class defined as

```
class Example {
    String name
    EnumObject desiredToTransform
}
```

There is a GET Rest service returning the JSON of an instance of this object as:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Albert"
    "desiredToTransform": {
         "id": "EXAMPLE_ID",
         "label":"Example value"
    }
}
```

The `create` Rest service for this object, receives the following arguments: `[name: String, desiredToTransform:String]`. If we want to create an object of this instance, we must do the following:

```
curl -X POST <POST_URL> -d '{"name":"Jhon Doe", "desiredToTransform":"EXAMPLE_ID"}'
```

**The problem**:
The solution I found was to create a directive which receives the model and transform the result as desired

[A plunker with the solution can be found here](https://plnkr.co/edit/AVukktDQLeVwEkcUFLcm?p=preview), and shown at next on snippet

```js
// Code goes here
var app = angular.module("app", []);

function rselectForEnum($http, $compile) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      var parent = angular.element(elem.parent());
      var enumerativo = attrs.enum || attrs['data-enum'] || "";
      var idElem = attrs["id"] || new Date().getTime().toString();
      var nameElem = attrs["name"] || idElem;
      var modeloElem = attrs.ngModel;
      if (typeof modeloElem === "undefined") {
        throw Error("De especificar el modelo");
      }
      //The original data receive a parameter for a REST service in order to gather the data
      // $http.get(config.apiUrl + "enumerativo/getEnum?c=" + enumerativo).then(function (response) {
      //     scope[nameElem + "EnumList"] = response.data.lista;
      // }, function (response) {
      // });

      //I am going to replace it with this code
      scope[nameElem + "EnumList"] = [{
        id: "EXAMPLE_1",
        label: "Exampple 1"
      }, {
        id: "EXAMPLE_2",
        label: "Exampple 2"
      }, {
        id: "EXAMPLE_3",
        label: "Exampple 3"
      }, {
        id: "EXAMPLE_4",
        label: "Exampple 4"
      }, {
        id: "EXAMPLE_5",
        label: "Exampple 5"
      }, ]


      var htmlSelect = "<select id='" + idElem + "' " +
        "name='" + nameElem + "' " +
        " class='form-control'>" +
        "</select>";
      var elemento = angular.element(htmlSelect);
      elemento.attr("data-ng-model", attrs.ngModel);
      elemento.attr("ng-options", "item.id as item.label for item in " + nameElem + "EnumList track by item.id");
      parent.append(elemento);
      elem.remove();
      $compile(parent)(scope);
    }
  }
}

app.directive('rselectforenum', ['$http', '$compile', rselectForEnum]);

app.controller("PruebaController", PruebaController);

/*@ngInject*/
function PruebaController($scope) {

  var vm = this;

  $scope.modelo = {
    enumerativo: {
      "id": "EXAMPLE_2",
      "label": "Example 2"
    }
  };

  vm.wizzard = {

  };

  init();
  return vm.wizzard;

  function init() {
    // initialize tuffs here
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js
"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>How to transform the model with a select component?</h1>
    
    <div ng-controller="PruebaController">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label class="">Probando</label>
        <div class="form-line">
            <rselectForEnum
                    id="rselectForEnumId"
                    data-ng-model="modelo.enumerativo"
                    enum="EstadoCivil"
            ></rselectForEnum>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  This is the value: 
    {{modelo.enumerativo}}
</div>
<br/>
<div class="row">
  This is the list:<br/>
    {{rselectForEnumIdEnumList}}
</div>

</div>

  </body>

</html>
```

The result turned on the following behaviors:

1. When the content is loaded, the select input is selected with the model value (**DESIRED**)
2. The model keep it original value (**NOT DESIRED**)
3. On change value, model got the id attribute (**DESIRED**)
4. At first modification on the select, the label turns blank, but value is right (**NOT DESIRED**)
5. If you do not change the select and sent the form to backend, the original value is sent (**NOT DESIRED**)

How can I fix this?